# Is there a mean to reboot WinCE 5.0 programmatically?

Tags: windows-ce

I am very new to WinCE, sorry if the question is stupid.
Is there something for rebooting a WinCE 5 system by executing a command ( like "shutdown -r now" on Linux) or by calling an API-Function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2890475.php) and [the IOCTLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms903744.aspx) will yield useful results. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KernelIoControl with IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT is the API way (if the OS supports it).  There is no standard command-line app that does it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it out, hope it is supported on customer's system

Answer (score 3):

Use API SetSystemPowerState(NULL, POWER_STATE_RESET, 0);